# DbFlow with RecyclerView.Adapter or CursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter, android-recyclerview, dbflow

Anyone know how to implement an adapter that receives data from a content resolver created with dbflow?

I have database, provider and model class created but how interact with adapter? Is RecyclerView Adapter the best option for my needs? I have seen I something about ModelViewAdapter from dbflow but I still trying to understand how to implement using it.

Answer (score 0):

You need a constructor in the adapter that receive your model class. for example:

```
public BeneficiaryListAdapter(Context context, List<Beneficiary> beneficiaryList){
        mContext = context;
        mBeneficiaryList = new ArrayList<>(beneficiaryList.size());
    }
```

In my activity I receive a list of beneficiaries so, when that happens the next is to do the intance of the `BeneficiaryListAdapter` and I pass the context and the the list `List<Beneficiary> beneficiaryList`  (in this case `Beneficiary` is my model class).

```
 mAdapter = new BeneficiaryListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), beneficiaryList);
```

Also, In my adapter, I have two class variables one that they will contain the `context` and other for the list that I am going to receive in the constructor.